# jquery jqXHR responseText convert string to JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxhr

I have some responseText that looks like this:

```
[{
        "id": null,
        "partId": 0,
        "name": "5e8c8c89-445e-4033-80db-014a00cc055e.jpg",
        "type": "image/png",
        "size": 2276489,
        "progress": "1.0",
        "url": "/Public/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx?id=5e8c8c89-445e-4033-80db-014a00cc055e.jpg",
        "thumbnail_url": null,
        "delete_url": "/Public/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx?id=5e8c8c89-445e-4033-80db-014a00cc055e.jpg",
        "delete_type": "DELETE",
        "error": null
    }
]
```

but I can not consume that data in my complete function. I have tried converting it to JSON using the $.parseJSON function but although I get an object, I can't access any of the items...

```
var o = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
console.log(o.partId); // returns undefined
```

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers,
r3plica

Comment: Most likely you are accessing the responseText before the request is complete, but without more context, we can't tell. It's rare that you actually need to use the responseText directly at all.

Comment: JSON is already a string. It sounds more like you want to convert a JSON string to a Javascript object.

Comment: Did you try `o[0].partId`?

Comment: @KevinB I need to get to the reponseText because I am returning an ID from my UploadHandler using BlueImp Upload with MVC. It uploads to s3 so I need to record my Id to the database along with the file location, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON response has an Array at the top level. You need to do:

```
console.log(o[0].partId);
```

Comment: thanks :) that was right. I knew it was an array but didn't think to use [0] lol. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jqXHR.responseJSON`:

```
console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON[0].partId);
```

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON`
> before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
> JSON object is made available through the `responseJSON` property of
> the `jqXHR` object.

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/